# Oracle XE 11g (windows 8) I can't connect to the Database (idle instance)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have problem with idle instance

When I trying:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

I get result: `Connected to an idle instance.`

And when I try startup I get:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-01565 error in identifying file 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs/spfileXE.ora
ORA-27041: unable to open file
ORA-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) File not found;
```

My system is Windows 8. Do you any idea how to solve it?

SOLUTION:
I have to startup using command:

```
startup pfile='<path to file>/init.ora'
```

and change all paths in init.ora where was

```
<ORACLE_BASE>
```

Thx for help

Comment: where is your spfileXE.ora file located? Or, what other files like spfile*.ora exist in the C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs directory?

Comment: there is only one file init.ora

Comment: with what exact name and location?

Comment: yes, location: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs and name is init.ora

Comment: this init.ora file is not used. Normally Oracle expects to find a file with initXE.ora or spfileXE.ora, if your database instance is called XE.

Comment: ok, I copied files from folder database where were spfileXE.ora and initXE.ora but now after startup I get: ORA-01506 missing or illegal database name. Do U know where I can set this and how?

Comment: Take a look in my answer and dive into the 2 Day DBA manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got that pain too.

To install Oracle XE you should login as local admin - NOT domain account.
This https://community.oracle.com/thread/2361291 made me happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
You just have to start the setup to install the database as administrator.
After this and a reboot everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading the [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm) manual, or hire a dba.

You are missing the init{ORACLE_SID}.ora, the parameter file which contains things like database name, controlfile locations. the init{ORACLE_SID}.ora is a text file that is edited with a regular text editor. This file can be converted to a spfile{ORACLE_SID}.ora that can be edited using a database instance. This is also a dynamic parameter file meaning that when you change parameters in an instance, the parameters can also be recorded in the spfile for later reuse.

For now add the db_name and control_files. Make sure that the contol_files parameter points to an existing controlfile[s]. If there are no existing control_file[s], just trash the initXE.ora, spfileXE.ora and start dbca, the Database Configuration Assistant and using that create a new database.